# Text wrap problem with body and aside element

Tags: html, css

I am working on incorporating an [`<aside>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/aside.html) element into the right side of an HTML page and I'm having some problems with text wrapping. The text within the body of the page is not wrapping and is instead running into the `aside' element. Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `<aside>`? I think HTML5 has officially jumped the shark. :P

Answer (score 0):

there is a css attribute called word-wrap, as seen [in this website](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap)..this is probably what you want?

```
.break-word {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. sorry if i didn't adequately explain my problem. i solved my issue with adding `padding-right: 220px;` to my HTML body. (220px is the width of my `<aside>' element.)